# create a list of dictionaries from a list of keys and a list of list of values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Following is the keys which will be used to create a dictionary.

```
keys = ['a', 'b','c']
```

adding to the challenge is that list of lists of values with varying level of nesting within the items, these need to be flattened but only if it has only one item. For example, `[3,3,5]` shouldn't be flattened because it represent a group.

```
values = [
[[1],[1],[1]],
[[1],[0],1],
[2,0,[3,3,5]],
[1,[[1]],0]
]
```

I tried `print dict(zip(key_list, cols))` but this doesn't seem to quite generate the expected output:

```
[{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1} , {'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':1}, {'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':[3,3,5]}]
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output? (post an example)

Comment: what about `[1,[[1]],0]` ?

Comment: @Kasra that would generate `{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':0}`

Comment: can you add the full expected output

Comment: In your example, all the objects in the input list are just lists or integers.  Is this a consequence of an implicit requirement of yours or is it just by chance?

Comment: Why is the list of lists of values so inconsistent? Maybe you should fix that. Also, one of the reasons you're received so many different answers is because your question doesn't clearly state what output you actually want for all the data in the test case.

Comment: @user299709 if none has answered your question do write your own answer and enlighten us, else mark any of the answers as accepted

Answer (score 2):

Given your input and expected output, you can overcome the single nested challenge by using loops. 
The program can be written as

```
values = [
[[1],[1],[1]],
[[1],[0],1],
[2,0,[3,3,5]],
[1,[[1]],0]
]
keys = ['a','b','c']
l = []
for i in values:
    d = dict()
    for j in range(3):
        ele = i[j]
        while isinstance(ele,list) and len(ele) == 1:
            ele = ele[0]
        else:
            d[keys[j]] = ele
    l.append(d)     
print (l)
```

With the output

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': [3, 3, 5]}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}]
```

as expected. (but as dictionaries are hashed the order would have been different)

**NOTE** - I have used **SHORT CIRCUIT EVALUATION** to prevent use of multiple condition statements

Answer (score 1):

Because of deep-nesting you need to recursively or iteratively flatten single element lists. I used `get_flat` to do it according to your specification.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# flatten single element lists recursively.
# using a while loop is probably better
def get_flat(elem):
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        if len(elem) > 1:
            return elem
        else:
            return get_flat(elem[0])
    return elem

values = [
    [[1],[1],[1]],
    [[1],[0],1],
    [2,0,[3,3,5]],
    [1,[[1]],0]
]
keys = ['a','b', 'c']

# zip keys and values for each flat column (uses get_flat to flatten)
# and convert to dict
print map(dict, map(lambda col: zip(keys, map(get_flat, col)), values))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 0}, {'a': 2, 'c': [3, 3, 5], 'b': 0}, {'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first you need to flat your values , you can do it with following recursion function :

```
>>> def flat(l):
...  if not any(isinstance(i,list) and len(i)==1 for v in l for i in v):
...   return l
...  else :
...   return flat([[i[0] if isinstance(i,list) and len(i)==1 else i for i in v] for v in l])
... 

>>> flat(values)
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, [3, 3, 5]], [1, 1, 0]]
```

then use the following list comprehension :

```
>>> [dict(zip(keys,l)) for l in flat(values)]
[{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 0}, {'a': 2, 'c': [3, 3, 5], 'b': 0}, {'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 1}]
```

but this gave you a dictionary list with 4 item , and you want 3 , mean that you want one dict for `[1, 0, 1]` and `[1, 1, 0]` , thus you need to remove one of them you can do it with sorted them and an list comprehension :

```
>>> p=[sorted(i) for i in flat(values)]
>>> [j for i,j in enumerate(p) if p[i+1:].count(j)<1]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 2, [3, 3, 5]], [0, 1, 1]]

>>> [dict(zip(keys,l)) for l in last_l]
[{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 0, 'c': [3, 3, 5], 'b': 2}, {'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function which can flatten your list based on level of nested list you have.

Like in your case max level of nested list is 2 for `[[1]]`

```
def get_values(values,count):
    for i in range(count):
        count = count - 1
        values = [[each[0] if isinstance(each, list) and len(each) ==1 else each for each in val] for val in values]
        return get_values(values,count)
    else:
        return values

keys = ['a', 'b','c']
values = [
        [[1],[1],[1]],
        [[1],[0],1],
        [2,0,[3,3,5]],
        [1,[[1]],0]
        ]       
count = max([str(each).count('[') for row in values for each in row if isinstance(each, list)])
# count = 2
print [dict(zip(keys, each)) for each in get_values(values, count)]
```

Results:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 0}, 
{'a': 2, 'c': [3, 3, 5], 'b': 0}, {'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 1}]
```

---

If the level of max nesting is 3 you just have to pass 3 as a parameter to the recursive function.

For example here values have max nesting of level 3 for element `[[[1]]]` so we just have to pass 3 as count parameter value for `get_values` function :

```
keys = ['a', 'b','c']
values = [
        [[1],[1],[1]],
        [[1],[0],1],
        [2,0,[3,3,5]],
        [1,[[[1]]],0]
        ]       

count = max([str(each).count('[') for row in values for each in row if isinstance(each, list)])
# count = 3
print [dict(zip(keys, each)) for each in get_values(values, count)]
```

Results:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 0}, 
{'a': 2, 'c': [3, 3, 5], 'b': 0}, {'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 1}]
```

Comment: can you explain whats the difference between your answer and mine ? however yours is defective !

Comment: @Kasra Please see my updated answer, before it was not handling for the case of `[[1]]`.

Comment: the problem is not `[[1]]` the OP wants the something like set for its values after flatting them ! any way i think its better to delete your answer ! as you put it 6 min after me !

Comment: @Kasra I cann't delete my answer because I had putten lot of effort for this and I'm sorry that i got 6 min late than you but I was trying to give a better result which can be producting for any amount of nesting.

Comment: @user299709 Please review the above solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming your last sentence means 
   [{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1} , {'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':1}, {'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':[3,3,5]}]
is your expected output.

Then

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [
[[1],[1],[1]],
[[1],[0],1],
[2,0,[3,3,5]],
[1,[[1]],0]
]

print [dict(zip(keys, entry)) for entry in values]
```

is your desired result.

```
[{'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'c': [1]}, {'a': [1], 'b': [0], 'c': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': [3, 3, 5]}, {'a': 1, 'b': [[1]], 'c': 0}]
```

Your problem is that zip(keys,values) treats each list making up values as the value that the key will point to.  So you got

```
{'a': [[1], [1], [1]], 'c': [2, 0, [3, 3, 5]], 'b': [[1], [0], 1]}
```

Comment: Oops - missed your flattening issue.  Saw a different bug in your code and corrected that.